# SwiftUI: Trying to create an array of Colors from a custom extension

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made an extension to `Color` to be able to use hex codes, which is used as `Color(hex: #fff000)` and works.

Color Extension:

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let trimHex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let dropHash = String(trimHex.dropFirst()).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let hexString = trimHex.starts(with: "#") ? dropHash : trimHex
        let ui64 = UInt64(hexString, radix: 16)
        let value = ui64 != nil ? Int(ui64!) : 0
        // #RRGGBB
        var components = (
            R: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            a: CGFloat(1)
        )
        if String(hexString).count == 8 {
            // #RRGGBBAA
            components = (
                R: CGFloat((value >> 24) & 0xff) / 255,
                G: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
                B: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
                a: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
            )
        }
        self.init(.sRGB, red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, opacity: components.a)
    }

}
```

---

In one of my views, I am trying to create an array of these

```
   @State private var colorViews: [Color] = []
   @State private var country: Country

   var body: some View {

   }
   .onAppear {
       print(self.country.colors) // ["#ff0000", "#ff0001"]
      
        if let colors = country?.colors {
            for color in colors {
                colorViews.append(Color(hex: String(color)))
            }
        }
        print("XXX", colorViews) // I get an array of hexs again but not in the extension format I made.  
    }
```

I am not sure what I doing wrong and trying to get an array of the format of my extension.  Example: `[Color(hex: "#ff0012"), Color(hex: "#ff0000")]`

Comment: You mean you want to get `[Color(hex: "#ff0012"), Color(hex: "#ff0000")]` as an output? Why? What's wrong with the default string representation?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to represent colors with 8 bits per channel anymore. Send that 255 back to the aughts.

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily a correlation between how a type is constructed and how it is printed by default. Just because you constructed the `Color` by doing `Color(hex: "#ff0000")`, that does not mean it will necessarily be printed as `Color(hex: "#ff0000")` when you print it.

How `Color` is printed is determined by the value of its `description` property, which can have an arbitrary implementation, and it certainly does not know about the existence of your extension.

If you really want that `Color(hex: "...")` format for some bizarre reason, you can add another extension to build the string using the components. An example of how to do this is shown below.

Note that even if you do this, you still will not be able to get the exact original string that was passed into the initialiser, with the exact capitalisations, leading/trailing whitespace etc.

```
extension Color {
    var rgbHexString: String? {
        guard let cgColor = cgColor,
            let components = cgColor.components,
            cgColor.colorSpace?.model == .rgb else {
            return nil
        }
        let hex = components.compactMap {
            String(Int(($0 * 255).rounded()), radix: 16)
        }.joined()
        return "#" + hex
    }
    
    var desiredFormat: String? {
        guard let hexString = rgbHexString else {
            return nil
        }
        return "Color(hex: \"\(hexString)\")"
    }
}
```

`desiredFormat` should not return `nil`, at least for colors created by your `init(hex:)` initialiser. It *would* return `nil` for things like `Color.accentColor`, because those are dynamic colors.

Then, you can `compactMap` your array of colors to `desiredFormat`:

```
print(colorViews.compactMap(\.desiredFormat))
```